# Using Spring autowired Service classes within a Liferay Indexer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay, autowired

I am using Spring @Service classes in my liferay portlet to get and store data. They are injected using the @autowired annotation. Everything is working as expected. When I am trying to use that same approach in a Liferay BaseIndexer subclass (to put data in the search engine) the @autowired annotated classes are all null (not injected).

Is there a way to get these Service classes in the Indexer ?

Best regards,

Daniel

Comment: This is somehow a duplicate of [Scheduled Tasks in Liferay with Autowired](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407340/scheduled-tasks-in-liferay-with-autowired), as you are trying to autowire into a class which is _not_ managed by Spring. Things from _...spring.xml_ files are managed by Spring, things from liferay-portlet.xml (like Indexers and Schedulers) are not managed by Spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indexer is not instantiated by Spring, so you won't be able to autowired your service.

But, you could implement a custom ApplicationContextProvider (implementing Spring ApplicationContextAware) and use it in order to inject your service. It should be easy.

You should start creating this class, and let Spring to discover it (be sure that this class is scanned by spring):

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Created by Alberto Martínez Ballesteros on 18/03/16.
 */

@Component("applicationContextProvider")
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context = null;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use this ApplicationContextProvider to inject your service within the indexer class:

For example:

```
public class CategoryIndexer extends BaseIndexer {

    private CategoryService categoryService;

    [....]

    @Override
    protected void doReindex(String className, long classPK) throws Exception {
        if (categoryService == null) {
            initService();
        }

        final Category category = categoryService.get(classPK);
        doReindex(category);
    }


    private void initService() {
        categoryService = (CategoryService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
                .getBean("categoryService");
}

[....]
```

As you can see, you can not use @Autowired in this way, but you can inject your bean anyway.

Regards.